# software for ubuntu that can emulate cd burning

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, burning, compact-disc, emulation

I don't want to waste my blank dvd's for a burning software that does not work. 
Do you know of any software that can emulate cd burning? Maybe emulate it by burning the data into a flash drive which is seen by the software as a cd or dvd. Is it possible?

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? Write data? for playback on typical dvd players?  PAL or NTSC format? Test a dvd iamge before making the commitment to burn it to disk?  If you make a dvd .iso image first, you could play it using a variety of players (mplayer comes to  mind) and then write the iso at once once you are happy with it.

Comment: an mpeg-4 compliant format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`k3b` can emulate burning, but I don't understand what do you mean by 'software that does not work'. Most of the software is working. Either you are not doing something right or your optical drive has issues.

Comment: I used brasero but not working. I'll try this k3b.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like to:

1. create a .iso image
2. mount the iso as loopback device, or dd it onto a usb-drive or something like that so you can test it...
3. burn iso to dvd when you are done.

---

**Update:** 
You can mount a iso directly with a loop back device.

```
mkdir test
mount -o loop my_test_project.iso test
```

Then in the dir called test you will see the content of the iso just as if it was a normal mounted cd/dvd.

Comment: what is a loop back device

Answer (score 0):

Most drives support a test-burn mode which simulates burning to disc but doesn't actually. Check to see if your preferred burning software on Ubuntu supports this mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you interested in paid solution, try Nero for Linux which supports Ubunutu and other linux flavours.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Brasero](http://projects.gnome.org/brasero/) it is also available in [Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=brasero). It checks the iso file for integrity and simulates a burn process before actually burning it. Very much Nero like but free !